Python Flask API with docker error in COPY --from=build /usr /usr
Suddenly my Dockerfile raised an error:

ERROR: failed to solve: cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/unmqsp2hwigzv0yjeufoloalx/merged/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Africa

My Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.9-slim as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app /app

COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages /usr/lib/python3.9

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["src/standalone.py"]

I tried to add below command but an error still occured:
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Africa

Then I tried to modify command which is the source of the error:
FROM:  COPY --from=build /usr /usr
TO: COPY --from=build /usr/ /usr/


Why do you use building image? Just use one image, copy the application source code with requirements.txt to /app directory and do pip install -r requirements.txt

@AndrejKesely mainly from the safety reasons

Copying all of /usr is likely to cause problems.  (And it somewhat defeats the point of using a "distroless" image, since it copies a significant part of the "distro" back in.)  Using a Python virtual environment here might be a little cleaner than trying to manipulate files inside /usr.

I'm not sure why you are using multi stage build for this app, but you could update your Dockerfile to something like (just select the best python image for you):
# FROM python:3.9-slim as build
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["src/standalone.py"]

I'm assuming that your Dockerfile and requirements.txt are inside your application folder.
